# What does \r\ mean in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, url, concatenation, line-breaks

I'm trying to add HTML around a field I have in a MySQL table that has URLs in it. What I have right now is this

```
select 
concat('<a href="', sourcelink,'">Link</a>')  as sourcelink  
from Table;
```

The first part of the concatination works for all the records, but only some of the records have the later part after the link. Have a look at this.

[image: Image of the results]

If I export the results to a spreadsheet, it becomes clear that the last part is there, but there's a line break.

[image: Screenshot of spreadsheet showing line breaks]

I've tried TRIM() and REPLACE() to get rid of extra spaces and line breaks, but nothing seems to work. Apologies if I'm not explaining this well enough!

Comment: That doesn't look like the output of your query. Your query puts doublequotes around `sourcelink`, but there aren't any doublequotes.

Comment: Did you load the sourcelinks from a CSV file? I suspect you used the wrong `LINES TERMINATED BY`. It should be `\r\n`, but you just used `\n`.

Comment: what trim and replace did you try?  do try removing both \r and \n

Comment: Barmar, I didn't export using LOAD DATA, I just used the export function in workbench. You're right though that the doublequotes are gone. I don't understand why that's happening. Either way though, if I quote a field in the results that doesn't have the last part, and paste it elsewhere, it shows  it on another line.

Comment: ysth, yes I tried replacing both \r and \n